# Create JQuery like plugin structure in custom javascript

Tags: javascript

**I DO NOT WANT TO CREATE A JQUERY PLUGIN**

Let's say I have something like this:

```
// In folib.js
function Foo() {this.Prop = function() {//do something}};
```

So my users can reference my JavaScript library and instantiate my object all day

```
// In consumer
foo = new Foo();
alert(foo.Prop);
```

Now, I want to create a JQuery like plugin system for my class, whereas I can create plugin script libraries which extend Foo().

I think I should be doing something like this...

```
(function( foo ){
    foo.myPlugin = function() {  
       // Do your awesome plugin stuff here
    };
})(Foo);
```

But I can't get that working. Any ideas on how this is done in JQuery? I can't figure it out :(

Comment: OK, follow me here...I'm thinking I need to do something like function Foo() {this.fn = function(script) {this.prototype.script;}};

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `prototype`:

```
Foo.prototype.myPlugin = function () { /* Do plugin stuff */ };
```

Then you will be able to access the plugin like so:

```
var foo = new Foo();
alert(foo.myPlugin);
```

Prototypes work when used in conjunction with `new`: the new object (`foo`) has a hidden pointer to the `prototype` object of the function it was constructed from (`Foo`). If a property isn't found on the new object, JS will search for it in the prototype. For more information, read [this](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#object.prototype).

jQuery does a similar thing by providing a `fn` property which points to `prototype`:

```
Foo.fn = Foo.prototype;
```

Answer (score 3):

To follow up on Box9's great answer, you should also return the object on which you are performing the action.

```
Foo.prototype.myPlugin = function () { 
     /* Do plugin stuff */ 

     return this; //return the object's instance
};
```

This will enable you to chain functions modifying the same object. This is part of what makes jQuery so popular--it uses a fluent interface which allows for more expressive syntax when chaining functions and plugins. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

This maybe not be what you were asking for, but it is particularly helpful when creating many functions extending an object.

```
myFooInstance.DoSomething(5).DoAnotherThing('hello').YetAnother();
```